# How to access the correct element on mouseover with javascript (chrome extension)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a program for a chrome extension that can return the url of a moused-over link from google search results. Right now I am able to log the urls of  tags, but not header tags, which most of the results appear as. The timeout call just delays the console log (irrelevant). When I inspect the google search results, the results show that they are  blocks, which I assume contain  tags embedded in them. How can I access the urls from these blocks?

My existing code that works on  elements:

...

```
document.addEventListener("mouseover", function(e){

    console.log("hello")
    if (e.srcElement.href != null)
    {

    var urlcheck = e.srcElement.href
    hoverTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
        console.log(urlcheck);

    }, 1000);
    
    
    } } )
```

...

Answer (score 0):

`srcElement` is deprecated, so changed to `target`.

```js
document.addEventListener("mouseover", function (e) {
  if (e.target.tagName != "DIV") return;
  if (e.target.className != "yuRUbf") return;
  const a = e.target.getElementsByTagName("a");
  console.log(a[0].href);
});
```